# SUMPRODUCT with certain conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, worksheet-function

I'd like to use the SUMPRODUCT (or other formula) with certain conditions to show results in the similar shape of a pivot table. 
I have a database "clients, cost-centers, months, revenues". For some of the clients we may have multiple cost-centers. I need the formula to show revenues depending on : clients, cost-centers, months alltogether in the same table, eventually in this matrix :

```
                                       Month1   Month2    Month3
Client_1       Cost_center1
               Cost center2
Client_2       Cost center1
               Cost center3
```

Comment: From what you've posted, there seems to be no reason why you couldn't do this with a pivot table rather than using SUMPRODUCT. It's much less work to use a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

=SUMPRODUCT in this situation seems pure masochism so providing you an answer may be depriving you of some pleasure, nevertheless:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$9=$F3)*--($B$2:$B$9=$G3)*--($C$2:$C$9=H$2)*$D$2:$D$9)
```

in H3, copied across and down to J6 may suit (for layout as example):

[image: SO14170112 example]

The PivotTable output below is included for comparison.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that if the asker has Excel 2007+, the Sumifs function might be a better option: `=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$9,$A$2:$A$9,$F3,$B$2:$B$9,$G3,$C$2:$C$9,H$2)`

Comment: Also +1 for image and pivot table comparison